# Can you Divide 2 completely different query results into 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, division

I'm trying to divide the numeric results from 2 pretty different queries.

The end result should be Query 1 DIVIDED BY Query 2

Query 1 =

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.ID)) AS count_1
FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN op 
    INNER JOIN Org 
    ON table1.EID = op.id 
        AND Op.OrgID = Org.ID
WHERE table1.TitleID = 123
    AND op.BrandID = 1 
    AND op.Start <= NOW() AND op.End >= NOW();
```

Query 2 =

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user.id) AS count_2
FROM table1 INNER JOIN user INNER JOIN ur
    ON table1.EID = user.id AND ur.userID = user.id
WHERE 
    user.BrandID = 1 
    AND table1.TitleID = 123
    AND ur.role = 0
    AND user.Inactive = 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!  You can use subselects to achieve this, though it will be pretty verbose!

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.ID)) AS count_1
    FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN op 
        INNER JOIN Org 
        ON table1.EID = op.id 
            AND Op.OrgID = Org.ID
    WHERE table1.TitleID = 123
        AND op.BrandID = 1 
        AND op.Start <= NOW() AND op.End >= NOW()
) / (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user.id) AS count_2
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN user INNER JOIN ur
        ON table1.EID = user.id AND ur.userID = user.id
    WHERE 
        user.BrandID = 1 
        AND table1.TitleID = 123
        AND ur.role = 0
        AND user.Inactive = 0
);
```

Format however it feels the least ugly to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use sub queries like this:

```
SELECT Q1.count_1 / Q2.Count_2 
FROM 
( ... Query1 ...) AS Q1
JOIN
( ... Query2 ...) AS Q2
ON 1=1
```

Replace Query1 and Query2 as your code.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
SELECT count_1 / count_2
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) count_1 FROM foo) f
JOIN  (SELECT COUNT(*) count_2 FROM bar) b ON 1=1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c215e/1